# generate a tag foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to make a simple pagination with jquery. My goal is put a page number in function "paginate();" then it will just append +5 times with 5 page number. I mean it will generate always +5 page a tag dynamically. I already tried with code bellow but its not looping though 5 times. again my goal is: generate 6,7,8,9,10 not 1,2,3,4,5

```js
function paginate(pageNumber) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pageNumber; i++) {
    //alert(i);
    $(".inner").append("<a href="
      "index?page=" + i + > "" + i + ""
      "</a>");
  }
}

paginate(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Pagination</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: it seems you have syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use should write it like 
    `$(".inner").append("<a href=\"index?page=" + i + "\">" + i + "</a>");`

You need to use `\` to escape the extra `"`, if you dont use `\` to escape, then the code with either think your starting or ending a string.

```js
function paginate(pageNumber) {
  for (var i = 6; i <= (pageNumber + 5); i++) {
    //alert(i);
    $(".inner").append("<a href=\"index?page=" + i + "\">" + i + "</a>");
  }
}

paginate(5);


function paginate2(pagestart, pageNumber) {
  for (var i = pagestart; i < (pagestart + pageNumber); i++) {
    //alert(i);
    $(".inner").append("<br><a href=\"index?page=" + i + "\">" + i + "</a>");
  }
}


paginate2(6,5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Pagination</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry i think you miss understood my goal. you are generating 1,2,3,4,5 but it should be 6,7,8,9,10

Comment: @JohnLk True i miss read that, please look at the updated answer

Comment: @JohnLk I've made a second version, where you can define the start number and how many times it should repeat the loop.

Answer (score 0):

write this way

```
$(".inner").append("<a href='index?page='" + i + ">" + i + "</a>");
```

```js
function paginate(pageNumber) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pageNumber; i++) {
    $(".inner").append("<a href='index?page='" + i + ">" + i + "</a>");
  }
}

paginate(5);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Pagination</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have a syntax in your code. This code will work correctly:

```html
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h2>Pagination</h2>
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<script>
    function paginate(pageNumber) {
        for (var i = 0; i < pageNumber; i++) {
            $(".inner").append("<a href=index?page=" + i +">" + i + "</a>")

        }
    }

    paginate(5);
</script>
```